# Display product name before attribute label in Woocommerce product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to change something in Woocommerce single product page but I could not find any post about it.

I would like to add the product name in front of all attributes label.
Like on product page named 'Car 1' with attribute 'Brand', 'Model' I would have

Car 1 Brand : Honda

Car 1 Model : XXX

Comment: What have you tried to do? You would have to write some code to achieve this, so show us some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the attribute label filter hook `woocommerce_attribute_label`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_attribute_label', 'custom_attribute_label', 1000, 2 );
function custom_attribute_label( $label, $name ) {
    global $product;
    if ( is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
        return $product->get_name() . ' ' . $label;
    }
    return $label;
}
```